# Selecting a specifik directory depending on its name as compared to the Id of an article item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, directory, path

I´m working on a personal side project, a web store, as an ASP.Net Core application with C#.

I'm trying to create an `ImageHandler` service that is to be used for fetching images that are located in a folder in the project.

I´m trying to structure the images so that they are easy to manage in the project with code, and to be easily overseeable, so I created a bunch of subfolders/directories.

The path looks like this:

```
WebRoot/Images/Articles/ArticleFolder/ArticleImages.jpg
```

The `Article` folder is named `Article.id_Article.Name` so a complete example would be:

```
 \wwwroot\Images\Articles\1_iPhone 13 Pro Max – 5G smartphone 128GB Silver\1_01.jpg.
```

I'm trying to write a statement that finds the right folder for a given article by making a selection on the first part of the folder name that is equal to the ID of the article it belongs to.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Enviroment.WebRootPath, "Images", "Articles");
string dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path).First(d => Path.GetFileName(d).StartsWith(articleId.ToString()));
```

But if I where looking for a image with the id of 1, the line would give me a directory starting with `10_article.Name` so obviously that wouldn't do.

I then tried:

```
string dir2 = Directory.GetDirectories(path).First(d => Path.GetFileName(d).Where(d => d.Split('_')[0] == articleId.ToString()));
```

I thought that would work, but I'm getting an error on the `d.Split('_')[0]`. It claims that d is now an char and therefore the method split can't be used. I understand that you somehow can save images as binary data in a SQL database and to keep images in the project folder might be dumb, as is my naming convention, but I'm curious how you could solve this. Any insight?

Comment: I think you mean `...First(d => Path.GetFileName(d).Split('_')[0] == articleId.ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, your structure is "/webroot/Images/Articles" (which remains constant), combined with /{articleId}+"_"+{articleName}/{imageName}, where the items in curly braces are variable, correct? How about something like this?

```
string imageRootFolder = Path.Combine(Enviroment.WebRootPath, "Images", "Articles");
string articleDir = Directory.GetDirectories(imageRootFolder).Where(dir => dir.StartsWith(articleId.ToString() + "_")).First();
List<string> pathsToImages = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(imageRootFolder, articleDir)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello! You understod it perfectly. I couldn't get your exact query to work, it found nothing ("sequence contains no elements"), but your idea to simply add the underscore {articleId.ToString() + "_"} worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!